# How do I mock a native javascript method with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

For example, I would like to test that `JSON.stringify` was called X times in a test. Can I do this with Jest? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can spy at native methods using [`spyOn`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname)

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(JSON, 'stringify')
console.log(JSON.stringify([{}]))
console.log(JSON.stringify([{}]))
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
```